# Effect of exec() after vfork() on parent's memory

Tags: exec, shared-memory, virtual-memory, copy-on-write, vfork

I'm currently reading Silberschatz's Operating Systems chapter on virtual memory.

Here it is stated that :

" *With vfork(), the parent process is suspended, and the child process uses the address space of the parent. Because vfork() does not use copy-on-write, if the child process changes any pages of the parent’s address space, the altered pages will be visible to the parent once it resumes.*

*[...] Vfork() is intended to be used when the child process calls exec() immediately after creation.* "

If I recall correctly, exec( ) will replace the current process image.

So dose calling vfork() with a subsequent exec() call replace the parent's process image as well since the address space is shared?

Comment: I'd suggest getting a new book. Vfork is an obsolete system service that hangs around for compatibility. The answer to your question NO. In theory it should, but this is all a hack.

Comment: @user3344003 Any suggestion on a good book on operating systems?

Comment: The best has been VAX/VMS Internals and Data structures. Used copies can be had cheaply. It described a real operating system without the academic BS.